# Command substitution vs I/O Redirection?

Tags: bash, shell, io-redirection, command-substitution

I am wondered about differences between **I/O Redirection** and **Command substitution**?

For example when I want to redirect `which` command output to `cd` command (I know that it's not a directory) then the `cd` command do not  use  `which` redirection.
For example `which w3af | cd`?
I have to use command substitution like `cd $( which w3af )`, why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the specific example you've cited, you need to use command substitution:

```
cd -P -- "$(dirname -- "$(which w3af)")"
```

for the simple reason that `cd` doesn't take input via `STDIN`.  It accepts only parameters.

Moreover, `which command` would produce a path to a file not a directory.

Comment: Thank you! I wrote that `which` command not produce a path. :)
Do you know how to check in easy way which commands take input via `STDIN`?

Comment: @koralgooll Usually the `man` pages would suggest that.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to test if a command will accept `stdin` or not. Mind you, this is hardly exhaustive:

```
% { wc ; cat ; } <<INTEST
    nope
INTEST

> 1 1 5

% { cd ; cat ; } <<INTEST
    nope
INTEST

> nope
```